# Best practice for relational sub-query via Wordpress wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

For a price comparison site, where people can find different suppliers for a product, I am running into this problem.

I made 3 custom post types:

- `product`, with taxonomy `ean`, and custom field `merchant_id` plus other product related custom fields;
- `merchant`, containing an entry for each merchant with information in custom fields. Taxonomy `merchant_id`;
- `merchant offer`, containing an entry for each product/merchant combination, with taxonomy `ean` and `merchant_id`.

Now I need a query on the product single page that displays all merchant offers for the particular product in "the loop". The result of the query should contain posts with for each post the merchant offer, PLUS some information from the merchant custom fields.

I looked for merging, nesting, relational or union wp_query but can not find a solution.

I want to use native Wordpress functionality like `wp_query` and "the loop", because this will be the most stable and update-proof, and because I want to use a filter that can filter on both `merchant` attributes as on the `merchant offer` attributes. The filter plugin that I want to use hooks on pre_get_posts.

When the solution contains two `wp_query` objects that will be merged, I think this won't be a problem for filtering because I can attach different filter id's to both queries. I can, in that case, create two filters in the back end; one for filtering on merchant fields and one for offer fields. On front end I will show them together.

Help for getting to a best practice would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best approach would be to leave the `product` query alone, so it deal only with that CPT but then, within "the loop", use `get_posts()`, so you don't screw with the main query, to retrieve the `merchant offer` posts that have the same `ean` as the current `product` post. You build your query args for the `get_posts` function in exactly the same ways as for wp_query. Something like:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  global $post;
  // Output some stuff about the product
  $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'merchant offer',
    ...
    'meta_query' => array(
      'meta_key'   => 'ean',
      'meta_value' => $post->ean,
    )
  );
  $offers = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ( $offers as $offer ) {
    // Output some stuff about each merchant offer
  }
  // Output any additional stuff about the product
endwhile;
```

If there are going to be a lot of merchant offers per product, to the extent that they would slow the page load, you might want to paginate them or just output a placeholder container in your single page for the product CPT, and add the merchants via ajax after the page has loaded. But that is a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks for your post, this is exactly what I did and it works very well!